# CI4 Inserting ID from selected Strings

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm so tired of thinking how to solve this case. already search by internet and never solved.
straight to the point

this is my Controller of Product.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Models\Model_product;
use App\Models\Model_category;
use App\Models\Model_status;
use App\Models\Model_supplier;

class Product extends Controller
{
    protected $helpers = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        helper(['form']);
        $this->model_category = new Model_category();
        $this->model_product = new Model_product();
        $this->model_status = new Model_status();
        $this->model_supplier = new Model_supplier();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['tbproduct'] = $this->model_product->getProduct();
        return view('product/index', $data);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $all = [
            'tbproduct' => $this->model_product->getProduct(),
            'tbcategory' => $this->model_category->getCategory(),
            'tbstatus' => $this->model_status->getStatus(),
            'tbsupplier' => $this->model_supplier->getSupplier()
        ];
        return view('product/create', $all);
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $validation =  \Config\Services::validation();

        $data = array(
            'prod_name'     => $this->request->getPost('prod_name'),
            'prodcat_id'    => $this->request->getGet('cat_id'),
            'prod_serial'   => $this->request->getPost('prod_serial'),
            'prod_barcode'  => $this->request->getPost('prod_barcode'),
            'prodstat_id'   => $this->request->getPost('stat_id'),
            'prodsup_id'    => $this->request->getPost('sup_id'),
            'prod_image'    => $this->request->getPost('prod_image')
        );

        if ($validation->run($data, 'product') == FALSE) {
            session()->setFlashdata('inputs', $this->request->getPost());
            session()->setFlashdata('errors', $validation->getErrors());
            return redirect()->to(base_url('product/create'));
        } else {
            $model = new Model_product();
            $simpan = $model->insertProduct($data);
            if ($simpan) {
                session()->setFlashdata('Success', 'Product has been created');
                return redirect()->to(base_url('product'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Models Model_product.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class Model_product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbproduct';

    public function getProduct($id = false)
    {
        if ($id === false) {
            return $this->table('tbproducts')
                ->join('tbcategory', 'tbproduct.prodcat_id = tbcategory.cat_id', 'left')
                ->join('tbstatus', 'tbproduct.prodstat_id = tbstatus.stat_id', 'left')
                ->join('tbsupplier', 'tbproduct.prodsup_id = tbsupplier.sup_id', 'left')
                ->get()
                ->getResultArray();
        } else {
            return $this->table('tbproducts')
                ->join('tbcategory', 'tbproduct.prodcat_id = tbcategory.cat_id', 'left')
                ->join('tbstatus', 'tbproduct.prodstat_id = tbstatus.stat_id', 'left')
                ->join('tbsupplier', 'tbproduct.prodsup_id = tbsupplier.sup_id', 'left')
                ->where('tbproduct.prod_id', $id)
                ->get()
                ->getRowArray();
        }
    }

    public function insertProduct($data)
    {
        return $this->db->table($this->table)->insert($data);
    }

    public function updateProduct($data, $id)
    {
        return $this->db->table($this->table)->update($data, ['prod_id' => $id]);
    }

    public function deleteProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->db->table($this->table)->delete(['prod_id' => $id]);
    }
}
```

and this is my Views create.php

```
<?php echo view('_partials/header'); ?>
<?php echo view('_partials/sidebar'); ?>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Create New Product</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Create New Product</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form action="<?php echo base_url('product/store'); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <?php
                                $inputs = session()->getFlashdata('inputs');
                                //$inputs_cat = isset($inputs['cat_id']) == null ? '' : $inputs['cat_id'];
                                $errors = session()->getFlashdata('errors');
                                if (!empty($errors)) { ?>
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                        Whoops! There is something wrong, that is:
                                        <ul>
                                            <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
                                                <li><?= esc($error) ?></li>
                                            <?php endforeach ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Product Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_name" placeholder="Enter product name" value="<?php echo isset($inputs['prod_name']); ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="col mb-3">
                                        <label for="">Category</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="cat_name" id="cat_name">
                                            <?php foreach ($tbcategory as $row) {
                                                echo '<option value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</option>';
                                            } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col mb-3">
                                        <label for="">Serial Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_serial" placeholder="Enter product serial number" value="<?php echo isset($inputs['prod_serial']); ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col mb-3">
                                        <label for="">Barcode</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_barcode" placeholder="Enter product barcode" value="<?php echo isset($inputs['prod_barcode']); ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="col mb-3">
                                        <label for="">Status</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="stat_name" id="stat_name">
                                            <?php foreach ($tbstatus as $row) {
                                                echo '<option value="' . $row['stat_id'] . '">' . $row['stat_name'] . '</option>';
                                            } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col mb-3">
                                        <label for="">Supplier</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="sup_name" id="sup_name">
                                            <?php foreach ($tbsupplier as $row) {
                                                echo '<option value="' . $row['sup_id'] . '">' . $row['sup_name'] . '</option>';
                                            } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url('product'); ?>" class="btn btn-outline-info">Back</a>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo view('_partials/footer'); ?>
```

i want to insert new data from Controller Product function store.
i've this problem, i cannot change string value into integer value for this

```
$data = array(
    'prod_name'     => $this->request->getPost('prod_name'),
    'prodcat_id'    => $this->request->getGet('cat_id'), ---->>> this is the problem
    'prod_serial'   => $this->request->getPost('prod_serial'),
    'prod_barcode'  => $this->request->getPost('prod_barcode'),
    'prodstat_id'   => $this->request->getPost('stat_id'), ---->>> and this
    'prodsup_id'    => $this->request->getPost('sup_id'), ---->>> and also this
    'prod_image'    => $this->request->getPost('prod_image')
);
```

if you see in the create.php Views, there is $row['***_id'] for all three tables.
and i want to grab that three ids into store.

and this is the Error shown:

```
mysqli_sql_exception #1048
Column 'prodcat_id' cannot be null
```

Comment: Show me the error

Comment: this is the error shown

'mysqli_sql_exception #1048
Column 'prodcat_id' cannot be null'

thank you, will be updated in the question area

Comment: What is the result of a a var_dump($data); after you've defined it. That will let you examine its contents. Can you post that up as well?

Comment: this is the result

`array(2) {
  ["prod_name"]=>string(20)"asdasdasdasdasdasdas"
  ["prodcat_id"]=>NULL
}`

thats it.

i just want the

` ["prodcat_id"] equals with cat_id` if i selected the category name

i.e cat_id "1" equals "Electronic"

if i selected the Electronic then the value of prodcat_id when i store is equal to 1 coz i've selected the Electronic which the value of cat_id is also 1

Comment: So in your URL you would need to have ?cat_id=2 as you are getting that from the URL using GET I.E.- 'prodcat_id'    => $this->request->getGet('cat_id'), So do you have that in the URL? By what you are getting I would say it's not there. You need to determine how you want to obtain your cat_id.

Comment: okay.. i would try that.. i will give the update later.  thank you TimBrownlaw

Comment: hi Tim sorry for long reply. i've tried but also failed.
here is my new adjustment code and the result in view.

adjustment code in View create.php

`<?php foreach ($tbcategory as $row) {
echo '<option value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_id'] . ' ' . $row['cat_name'] . '</option>';
} ?>`

new adjustment result from View create.php

1 Electronic <- this is just example result

the "1" value is i want to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for helping me before.
i found the answer.
here is the correct code where i can get the cat_id, stat_id and sup_id.

in the View create.php
change this code

```
<select class="form-control" name="cat_name" id="cat_name">
```

into this

```
<select class="form-control" name="cat_id" id="cat_id">
```

this mean you will get the cat_id value from the database, instead of cat_name.
change the stat_name into stat_id, then sup_name into sup_id.

when all of that changed, you can insert the database with the correct id number when you selected the value from the dropdown box.

this is the answer of my problem, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are sending the cat_name field not the cat_id field from the form. Fix the names of the fields and will works.

The below will works

```
<?php

$data = array (
    'prod_name'    => $this->request->getPost('prod_name'),
    'prodcat_id'   => $this->request->getPost('cat_name'), // ---->>> name fixed **
    'prod_serial'  => $this->request->getPost('prod_serial'),
    'prod_barcode' => $this->request->getPost('prod_barcode'),
    'prodstat_id'  => $this->request->getPost('stat_name'), // ---->>> and this **
    'prodsup_id'   => $this->request->getPost('sup_name'), // ---->>> and also this**
    'prod_image'   => $this->request->getPost('prod_image'),
);
```

Update:
Since this appears to be simple, but really this could be deceitful, i recommend the next steps to solve it:

1. Ensures that the form field names match with the named used on the php script
2. Ensure that you are sending data to the server. You can check the super globals. Something like print_r($_POST) is enough.
3. Ensure collect the data from the right source: get or post

In this case, the error comes from mysql. To mitigate this you can:

1. sets default values on columns if required
2. fill $data array conditionally. If there are no a cat_id, don't put an index 'cat_id' without value (or null)

Comment: i'm sorry the ** is a block for my problem.. sorry if it making confusing.. thank you i will fix the question area.

Comment: i refers that you are literally sending the wrong name from your form. Ex. you are sending the cat id under the name cat_name

Comment: thank you Jorge,

but it stil the same problem.

`Column prodcat_id cannot be null`

i just want the cat_name following the cat_id and the cat_id is going to be stored in prodcat_id

oh btw i've tried using getGet, getPostGet nothing is working

Comment: check the fields name in the html. Definitively these fields don't match with your php code.

Comment: ohhh, i see that you are getting cat_name from the get, not from the post. Answer updated.